# Removing Kestrel from ASP.Net 5 'empty' project

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I've made an 'empty' ASP.Net 5 project in Visual Studio 2015. The `project.json` file contains these lines

```json
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
},

"commands": {
  "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
},
```

I am testing on a Windows 10 development PC and planning to deploy to Azure and so, following the advice in [the docs on Servers](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html), I want to use IIS and not Kestrel.

However ripping Kestrel out is not straightforward. Firstly I remove the Kestrel related lines from the `project.json` file:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
},

"commands": {
},
```

This fails to build with multiple errors ("The type or namespace name 'Hosting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet'", "The type or namespace name 'DependencyInjection' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Extensions'", "The type or namespace name 'IServiceCollection' could not be found", and "The name 'WebApplication' does not exist in the current context") so I add `dependencies` to fix the errors, giving the following (which successfully builds)

```json
"dependencies": {
  "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
},

"commands": {
},
```

However it does not run - just hangs indefinitely but it also adds the line `"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"` back into the `commands` in `project.json`.

What should the `dependencies` and `commands` section of a `project.json` file in a "Hello World" ASP.Net 5 project look like if I do not want to use Kestrel, just IIS / IIS Express?

Comment: Should I be posting this question here or over on the aspnet/Hosting GitHub [issues](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> following the advise in the docs on Servers, I want to use IIS and not Kestrel.

This docs a bit outdated. You have to use Kestrel or another http listener supporting asp.net 5. Bigger info about Change to IIS hosting model [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69)

In a nutshell: Launch on IIS works through IISPlatformHandler Module, which works with http listeners such as Kestrel.